# Redshift Alter table with new columns in temp table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using following command in RedShift to add new columns (if any) to master table (`vendor_inspection_report`) form temporary table (`vendor_inspection_report_2023_12_19`).

```
Now Running : ALTER TABLE master.master_dbo.vendor_inspection_report APPEND FROM rab.rab_dbo.vendor_inspection_report_2023_12_19 FILLTARGET;
```

But I get

```
Execution Issue :  Columns don't match.
context:   Column "critical_defect_photos_captions" has different attributes in the source table and the target table. Columns with the same name must have the same attributes in both tables.
```

I have `critical_defect_photos_captions character varying(4000) ENCODE bytedict,` in both the tables.

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE APPEND is only for adding all rows (blocks actually) from one table to another.  The tables' DDL in question need to match exactly.  THis is just the wrong command for what you are doing. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html

You need to do an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN.  Then you need to INSERT the column data from the temp table.  You may want to do these steps in a transaction block to ensure that others don't see empty values for this column during the change.  Also note that this will drive the need for a full vacuum of the table as every row will have changed.

Alternatively you can create a new table with the old and new columns.  Then INSERT all the data joining the old and temp table data together and inserting all rows at once.  Then do a swap and drop.  No vacuum required but you will need to ensure data consistency manually if the table is possibly changing during the table update.